# Error in data output using write.csv in R

Tags: r, csv, quantmod

I want to download option prices using quantmod and save it into a csv file but failed.I don't know how ti fix it, thanks for any help.

```
temp <- getOptionChain("AAPL")
write.csv(temp, "AAPL_Option.csv")
```

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 36, 34

Comment: Can you show us what your data looks like and what class it is? This likely has to do with a rectangular ```data.frame```

Comment: `write.csv` is meant to write data in tabular form (data frames), your dataset `temp` is a list of *two*  data frames. You can use `save` to save the entire object `temp` to disk or write each df at a time. Something like `lapply(names(temp), function(nm) write.csv(temp[[nm]], paste0("AAPL_Option_", nm, ".csv")))`. Note that this appends the name of each df to `AAPL_Option`.